# querying for alumni of a particular school using graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i am querying for the list of facebook users who are an alumni of a particular school (ex sgsits) in the following way-

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=sgsits &type=user&access_token=abcd..
```

This works successfully.

But how do i modify this query to find out the list of people who passed out in any particular year..say 1986??

I tried using

```
  https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=sgsits 1986&type=user&access_token=abcd..
```

But this does not work.